# Central limit theorem for independent, non-identically distributed, finite discrete random variables

Tags: central-limit-theorem, discrete-distributions

I am positive, that there exists a version of CLT stating that, the distribution of the sum of infinite many independent, nonidentical, finite discrete random variables, is Gaussian. I just could not find the reference any more right now. Does anyone have the resource?

Edit: all the distributions are nondegenerate (in my case), but as the discussion and answer below pointed out, as long as the sum of their variances goes infinity, CLT applies.

Comment: This result is not true without further restriction.  Because the usual CLT could care less about whether the distribution is discrete, that criterion looks irrelevant.  "Nonidentical" unfortunately is far too vague to result in any kind of theorem: that's where we need restrictions.  Could you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: By nonidentical I meant those random variables have different PMFs, and their supports are finite (bounded)

Comment: Same problem.  At a minimum you would need to have a finite *uniform* bound on all supports.  Again, whether the variables are discrete or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @whuber, I think this is it: https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Introductory_Probability_(Grinstead_and_Snell)/09%3A_Central_Limit_Theorem/9.02%3A_Central_Limit_Theorem_for_Discrete_Independent_Trials Theorem 9.2.2

Comment: Your reference imposes that uniform bound as well as a condition on the variances (which is essential).  Why it might limit the statement to discrete variables is a mystery, though.  Maybe I'm overlooking some subtlety.

Comment: @whuber if all distributions are finite, aren't they uniformly bounded by a certain value? On the variances, I should have emphasized those are all non-degenerate distributions, which was the case I am working on.

Comment: Here's a counterexample: let *iid* $Z_i$ have a Bernoulli$(1/2)$ distribution and define $X_i=2^iZ_i$ for $i=1,2,3,\ldots.$  Every $X_i$ is bounded (and non-degenerate) but the sequence of $X_i$ is not uniformly bounded.  Moreover, despite the fact that the variances of the $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ diverge, it is evident that $S_n$ (even when standardized) will not be approximated by any Gaussian distribution (the sum looks ever more *uniform* as $n$ grows large).

Comment: @whuber I am confused by the example. Wouldn't $X_{\infty}$ be unbounded ? Since its maximum value is $\infty$? Do we have the same definition of being finite?

Comment: There is no such thing as "$X_\infty$" in this example.  Every one of the indices $i$ is a finite number. The definition of "finite" (really, "bounded")I am applying is that for each $i,$ there exists a natural number $N(i)$ for which $\Pr(|X_i|\le N(i))=1.$  Clearly $N(i)=2^i$ works. When such a value of $N$ can be found that does not vary with $i,$ we say the $X_i$ are *uniformly* bounded. This example shows that a sequence of bounded variables need not be uniformly bounded.

Comment: @whuber thanks! I saw the difference now.. another day when natural language fails in mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the most general CLT theorem to-date invokes the Lindeberg Feller condition to prove the asymptotic limiting normal distribution holds.

That is if a sequence of independent random variables $X_k$ satisfies the Lindeberg condition:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{s_n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E} \left[ (X_k - \mu_k) ^2 \cdot \mathcal{I}(|X_k - \mu_k| > \epsilon s_n)\right] = 0 \quad \forall \epsilon > 0$$

then the usual statement of the CLT applies. Note we make no statement about the distribution of $X_k$. The Lindeberg condition can be thought of as requiring that deviations get "swallowed" up with the standard error of the mean. It's interesting to consider some counterexamples to the Lindeberg condition, particularly where a finite mean exists by the WLLN.